# Can't enumerate through Jekyll pages by tag

Tags: html, ruby, yaml, jekyll

#### goal

Generate a page list filtered by a single tag.

#### problem

List doesn't appear.

#### things I tried

I started with the `<nav>` element in the default Jekyll site:

```
<nav class="site-nav">
<div class="trigger">
  {% for page in site.pages %}
    {% if page.title %}
      <a class="page-link" href="{{ page.url | prepend: site.baseurl }}">{{ page.title }}</a>
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
</div>
</nav>
```

When the Jekyll site is `serve`d, this puts an "About" page in the `nav` element.

I added two tags to different pages' front matter on the site:

```
tags:
- eng
---
```

I tried both formats:

```
tags: eng
---
```

1. Try enumerating through `site.tags.eng` (also tried `site.tags[eng]` and `site.tags["eng"]`):

   `<div class="trigger">
        {% for page in site.tags.eng %}
           {% if page.title %}
             <a class="page-link" href="{{ page.url | prepend: site.baseurl }}">{{ page.title }}</a>
           {% endif %}
         {% endfor %}
      </div>`
2. Try testing for a tag (with or without quotes):

   `<div class="trigger">
           {% for tag in site.tags %}
                     {% if tag == "eng" %}
               {% if page.title %}
               <a class="page-link" href="{{ page.url | prepend: site.baseurl }}">{{ page.title }}</a>
               {% endif %}
                     {% endif %}
           {% endfor %}
         </div>`
3. Also add a tag list to `_config.yml`:

   ```
   # Tags
   tags: [eng, jpn]
   ```
4. Add a tag to the sample post to see if only posts are being indexed

#### other questions I looked at

- [Generating a list of pages (not posts) in a given category](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17118551/generating-a-list-of-pages-not-posts-in-a-given-category): not sure how what I'm trying is fundamentally different
- http://jekyllrb.com/docs/variables/: the Jekyll main documentation doesn't say that tags have to be specified in the config YAML
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18944264/jekyll-plugin-liquid-tag-creation-not-working: It doesn't seem like I should have to build a whole plugin for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Settings tags on a page :

```
tags: [ tag1, tag3 ]
---
or
tags:
 - tag1 
 - tag2
---
```

If you want to make a list from a tag :

```
<ul>
  {% for p in site.pages %}
    {% if p.tags contains 'tag2' %}
    <li><a href="{{ p.url | prepend: site.baseurl }}">{{ p.title }}</a></li>
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Secondary answers :

- It's normal for about page to appear in pages list (default menu) it's a page
- Tagged pages will not appear in **site.tags** hash, only posts.

Comment: Perfect. I guess I was just getting lost in the woods.

Comment: This IS perfect!  Man I spent so many hours barking up every wrong tree in those same woods and was nearly convinced this wasn't possible.  Many many thanks, David!