# Getting a list documents in a folder

Tags: jekyll

I've setup up some content in Jekyll that's properly generating files in a folder

docs/
    index.html
    /install/index.html
    /features/index.html

What I want to do is get a list of those documents (similar to "site.posts") that I can use to render the list and their links. I've read varying approaches related to using collections (which are unstable), or injecting large amounts of liquid code/script (which I'm not entirely comfortable with). So hoping there's a simpler way to get Jekyll to generate my "docs" collection so I can use it.

Any pointers? Or am I stuck doing something like this: [Generating a list of pages (not posts) in a given category](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17118551/generating-a-list-of-pages-not-posts-in-a-given-category)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can try :

```
site.pages
```

And if you want only some pages you can add a variable in each page front matter like `selection: true`. Then do a

```
{% assign selection = site.page | where: 'selection', true %}
```

Now you can loop on `selection` which contains only needed pages.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you. I added in some tags to filer on and I can get to exactly what I was after.